# How to Bind a group by data in view in mvc5? what are the best ways to do

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using `Entityframework` context, i dont know how to bind to view.

I am grouping items by gender

```
public SQLChallengeEntities Sqlcontext = new SQLChallengeEntities();

var bookGrouped = Sqlcontext.Empinfoes.ToList()
.GroupBy(x => x.EmpSex).ToList();

return View(bookGrouped.ToList());
```

In View How to get the data

```
   @foreach (var s in Model)
   { 
        @group.Sex 
        foreach (var book in s.Values) 
        { 
            @s.Empname
            @s.EmpDesignation @s.EmpAge 
        }
   }
```

I am getting this error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Linq.IGrouping2[System.String,Angular‌​CrudS.Empinfo]]'`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `'System.Linq.IGrouping2[System.String,AngularCrudS.Empinfo]'`

Comment: what do you expect to get after grouping?

Comment: @teovankot; OP is expecting to have `@group.Sex`

Comment: Remove all the .ToList() calls.

Comment: i am just grouping by  Empdesignation but i have grouped in and store in  var bookGrouped = Sqlcontext.Empinfoes.ToList()
.GroupBy(x => x.EmpDesignation); return view(bookGrouped); but when i go to view i got an error  How to pass it to view ,Why view not get the data

Comment: Show the model you're using in your view in the question please. `@model ModelClassHere`

Comment: model IEnumerable<AngularCrudS.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Groups";
}
<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) {

foreach(var s in item)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(s => s.Eid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(s => s.Employeename)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(s => s.EmpAge)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(s => s.EmpSex)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(s => s.Designation)
        </td>
        
    </tr>
}
}
</table>

Comment: So .. your model is `@model IEnumerable<AngularCrudS.Employee>`?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to change that to `@model IEnumerable<AngularCrudS.Empinfo>`...

Comment: @sippy model class is not a problem ,Its in generic list , It requires Igrouping , I dont know how to do that Error is:The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,AngularCrudS.Empinfo]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,AngularCrudS.Empinfo]'.

Comment: Yeah because you keep calling .ToList() everywhere, stop calling ToList.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have `@group.Sex` you need to have a model like

```
public class EmployeeSexGroupModel
{
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AngularCrudS.Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query would be

```
var bookGrouped = Sqlcontext.Empinfoes
    .GroupBy(x => x.EmpSex).Select(x => new EmployeeSexGroupModel { Sex = x.Key, Employees = x});

return View(bookGrouped.ToList());
```

Your view would then look like

```
@model List<EmployeeSexGroupModel>
@foreach (var s in Model)
{
    @s.Sex
    foreach (var e in s.Employees)
    {
        @e.Empname
        @e.EmpDesignation @e.EmpAge
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GroupClass
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<Shahriar> shahriarList { get; set; }
}

        var list = db.Shahriars.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new GroupClass(){
          
                      Key = x.Key,

                      shahriarList = x.ToList()

                   }).ToList();

        ViewBag.Data = list;
```

```
@foreach (var x in (List<GroupClass>)ViewBag.Data)
{
    <tr><td colspan="4" style="background-color:lightblue;">@x.Key</td></tr>

    foreach (var y in x.shahriarList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@y.Id</td>
            <td>@y.Name</td>
            <td>@y.Roll</td>
            <td>@y.Mobile</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```